# Summing list of counters in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, counter

I am looking to sum a list of counters in python. For example to sum:

```
counter_list = [Counter({"a":1, "b":2}), Counter({"b":3, "c":4})]
```

to give `Counter({'b': 5, 'c': 4, 'a': 1})`

I can get the following code to do the summation:

```
counter_master = Counter()
for element in counter_list:
    counter_master = counter_master + element
```

But I am confused as to why `counter_master = sum(counter_list)` results in the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Counter'` ? Given it is possible to add counters together, why is it not possible to sum them?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function has the optional *start* argument which defaults to 0. Quoting the linked page:

> `sum(iterable[, start])`
>
> Sums *start* and the items of an *iterable* from left to right and returns
>   the total

Set *start* to (empty) `Counter` object to avoid the `TypeError`:

```
In [5]: sum(counter_list, Counter())
Out[5]: Counter({'b': 5, 'c': 4, 'a': 1})
```

Comment: While this is the most elegant looking solution, it is actually terribly slow regarding the way it is executed.

Answer (score 4):

This version was faster in my experience. This is upper bound by O(log(n)).

```py
def sum_counters(counter_list):

    '''
    Recursive counter with a O(log(n)) Complexity
    '''

    if len(counter_list) > 10:

        counter_0 = sum_counters(counter_list[:int(len(counter_list)/2)])
        counter_1 = sum_counters(counter_list[int(len(counter_list)/2):])

        return sum([counter_0, counter_1], Counter())

    else:

        return sum(counter_list, Counter())

global_counter = sum_counters(counter_list)
```