# Putting a set of counter in a list

Tags: python, list, counter

I have a result of my_counter_list like these:

- Counter({u'holmes': 1, u'heard': 1, u'woman': 1, u'sherlock': 1})
- Counter({u'twist': 1, u'place': 1, u'oliver': 1, u'where': 1, u'treats': 1})
- Counter({u'vowed': 1, u'washington': 1, u'monday': 1, u'democrats': 1})

But what I would like to get is:

> my_list = [Counter({u'holmes': 1, u'heard': 1, u'woman': 1, u'sherlock': 
>    1}), Counter({u'twist': 1, u'place': 1, u'oliver': 1, u'where': 1, u'treats': 1}), Counter({u'vowed': 1, u'washington': 1, u'monday': 1, u'democrats': 1})]

in order to sum them like [Summing list of counters in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003466/summing-list-of-counters-in-python)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just put the three individual variables into a list? Like `my_list = [c1, c2, c3]`? How exactly does the "result" of `my_counter_list` look like? Does the function just `print` the counters? In this case, change the function to `return` or `yield` them.

Comment: If you have a list of Counters, why not call `sum(my_counter_list)` directly?

Comment: Thanks `@Eric Duminil`, but using `sum(my_counter_list)` gives this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'unicode'` `@tobias_k`, the comments done for `@Charlie` below can also be applied to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Put it into a list as you normally would with any object.

```
from collections import Counter

cnt1 = Counter()

cnt2 = Counter()

cnt3 = Counter()

for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
  cnt1[word] += 1

print cnt1

for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
  cnt2[word] += 1

print cnt2

for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
  cnt3[word] += 1

print cnt3

my_list = [cnt1, cnt2, cnt3]

print my_list
```

This outputs the following:

```
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})
[Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1}), Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1}), Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})]
```

Comment: Thanks `@Charlie`. But I put three examples of counter just to illustrate. In fact the result of `my_counter_list = Counter(terms)` with `print(my_counter_list)` can be more than three cnt i.e `cnt1`, `cnt2`, `...`, `cntN`. This depends on the size of the input data. This remark can be applied to `tobias_k`'s answer